# Tag helper is not rendered

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I trying to use tag helper. But i have a problem about tag helper render. if i use tag helper, it isn't render. But if i use Razor tags, it is render. I share my chrome developer console screenshot. It seems there, tag helper isn't render . Below there is a example of my code. Can you explain me, why i have this problem. I research this but i didnt find solution.

My code:

```razor
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Ldap, Html.GetEnumSelectList<Ldap>(), " -- Nothing -- ", new { @class = "form-control" })

<!-- Tag Helper -->
<select asp-for="Ldap" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Ldap>()" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

_ViewImports.cshtml;

```
@using MvcUI
@using MvcUI.Models
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

[Chrome developer console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvenq.png)

Comment: It would be more useful if you could describe *some problem* here. Also, please include your `_ViewImports.cshtml` in the question.

Comment: Maybe `asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Ldap>()"` (add a `@`) works. But it would be better to add the items to your ViewModel.

Comment: @KirkLarkin i edited my question about _some problem_. And i share my viewimports codes

Comment: @HenkHolterman i try this but it didn't work for me.
It is already property in my ViewModel and i use this ViewModel

Comment: Your `_ViewImports.cshtml` looks ok with the correct `addTagHelper` directive. It’s clear that *none* of the tag-helpers are running on your page, which is odd. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks, i solved. It is about __ViewImports_ file. I forget define __ViewImports_ for new Area. So i create it and problem solved